# Sleep until a file is modified in python (linux)

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio

I would like to know whether there is any way to sleep an asyncio coroutine until a file is modified (not just polling with a short sleep in berween). The other SO questions on the topic predate asyncio, or only work on Windows. I know there is a way to do this on linux in general, but I would like to know what the simplest way to do it in python.

The one idea I had was to have *another* process wait until the change event, then send a notification to my python program via socket, but I would prefer a simpler method.

Comment: [`python-inotify`](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/)

Comment: If you know that the general way to do this on Linux is `inotify`, wouldn't it make sense to just Google "python inotify" to see if there's a library for it? Python has libraries for just about anything that's common.

Comment: I actually didn't know it was called lnotify, I just recalled having once done something with this in my OS class... Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Barmar The OP is explicit in the desire for the library to support asyncio, which python-inotify doesn't mention anywhere in the documentation. There are several async inotify libraries, of which [asyncinotify](https://asyncinotify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems the most actively maintained.

Comment: @user4815162342 `inotify` is just a way to be notified of changes to a file. Why would it matter that the application uses asyncio after it gets the notification?

Comment: @Barmar It matters because notifications need to be delivered through asyncio-compatible mechanisms to be picked up by the program running inside the asyncio event loop. Asyncio is specific in that it unfortunately requires the entire program to be structured around it and specifically prohibits the use of blocking calls, or "async" callbacks delivered in a different thread, as implemented by libraries predating asyncio. (Of course, both can be integrated through compatibility APIs, but those involve the use of threads and come with various limitations.)